# Re-scaling x, y-axis on capture correct coordinate scale on mouse-over in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am rendering a data as shown below using cluster analysis. 
[image]

As you can see that ports in the range of 0-200 are clubbed together. Is there a way to zoom in on the scale when I mouse over a coordinate and thereby redrawing that section of the graph again in a zoomed window. What i mean is that for the coordinates shown in blue circle, when I mouse over, I want the x, y axis redrawn for 0-10000 using a different scale so that overlapping circles move apart. Is it possible ?.  I must confess I find matplotlib little challenging and my apologies if my question is little cryptic. thanks for the help!

Comment: If I have misunderstood you I apologise but I think that function is built in to pyplot. Do you have the pyplot buttons below your plot?

Comment: Note that what you are asking for here would create a little chaos; changing the limits on hover would result in a plot which would constantly update itself, which is probably undesired.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming youre using pyplot then this functionality is built right in to the pyplot output.

See the following from the [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/users/navigation_toolbar.html).

**The Zoom-to-rectangle button**

Click this toolbar button to activate this mode. Put your mouse somewhere over an axes and press the left mouse button. Drag the mouse while holding the button to a new location and release. The axes view limits will be zoomed to the rectangle you have defined. There is also an experimental ‘zoom out to rectangle’ in this mode with the right button, which will place your entire axes in the region defined by the zoom out rectangle.

If you need to enable zoom to rectangle functionality without actually clicking then this will be possible by creating a transparent figure positioned in a location of your choice on your plot and then initiating a matplotlib event to be handled when the mouse hovers over this area. This functionality is not built in and will require customisation.

Detail relating to event handling on mouseover events can be found at [this URL](https://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html#mouse-enter-and-leave)

Comment: thanks,but I wanted it to be context sensitive as I mouse over without clicking on the zoom button.